# What species is this fast-moving spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

This is a frame from a recent recording:

[image: 1]

### Location

Forest in Central Europe at around 1pm.

### Abiotic factors at the time of recording

- Temperature = 23°C
- Humidity = 38%
- Wind = 6 km/h

### Description

- Approximate size = ~3 cm including limbs
- Semi-transparent limbs and cephalothorax, opaque abdomen
- The abdomen presents a pattern which reminds me of the coat pattern in giraffe *G. camelopardalis tippelskirchii*
- its general morphology makes me think it might be part of Pholcidae family but I'm not entirely sure because the height of the abdomen seems a bit too bulbous on the Y axis
- web structure rather irregular

### Observed behavior

Very short reaction time (dropped a piece of leaf on top of its web), very fast moving spider. I can't provide a better estimation for the speed, but here's is the 3rd frame after the one above (on the previous two frames it just very slightly flexes its limbs):

[image: 2]

And one frame later it's already gone.

### Internet search

- Google image search: no results using the first image you see in this post
- Google text search: different sentences like "long-legged transparent forest spider" only returned the usual daddy long legs you can find at home in urban areas.
- Finally I tried https://spiderid.com/spiders/ selecting white and brown but none of the displayed spiders matches anything that resembles the frame above.

Any help will be much appreciated. I guess the pattern on the abdomen is key to identify this species but I haven't had a lot of luck while looking for abdominal spider patterns.

Comment: Go to iNaturalist and type in "spiders" as well as your country, then go to the species tab and scroll down until you find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a male Linyphiid, most probably a *Frontinellina frutetorum*

[image: Frontinellina frutetorum. Source: wikipedia]

Source: https://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/Linyphiidae/Linyphiidae.htm

Thanks to John Robinson and Ed Nieuwenhuys who helped get a probable match for this spider.

Answer (score 2):

Pawelek;

Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced at European spiders, but I suspect you're looking in the wrong place.  First of all, this appears to be an adult male spider (large ball-like structures at the ends of the pedipalps, in front of the 'face'), so the body pattern is probably going to be a bit different from the one you see on the females.  Male patterns are often an afterthought in identification references, unfortunately.

Secondly, this doesn't look much like a Pholcid to me - I'm getting more of a Linyphiid impression, from the shape of the abdomen, the visible patterns on cephalothorax and abdomen, and the filmy sheet it's hanging under.
I wish I could be of more help than this - but perhaps Ed Nieuwenhuys can help.  Here's a link to his site; if you look down toward the bottom, there's a contact link you could send him a photo and this question:

https://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/spidhome.htm

Comment: Hi, Pawelek - for some reason, the answer dropped the "Hi," I had put before your name, and it refused to let me add it in later.  Most odd and unfriendly!  At any rate, please don't think I would simply start right in in that brusque fashion.  I'm a grouch, but not an unfriendly one!

Comment: [Stack Exchange discourages "hi" and such salutation on the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) though.

Comment: John, I wrote to Ed and he confirmed it is a linyphiid as you suggested. He said it looks like a _Frontinellina frutetorum_. If you modify your answer to reflect this I'll be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, Pawelek;  That's a nice offer, but I would feel a bit dishonest if I modified my post to give a suggested species that I don't, in fact, know.  I'm glad Ed gave you a probable ID!

Comment: I suggested so because I wouldn't have been able to get such a close match if you hadn't pointed me to Ed's site :) (for which I'm thankful). I'll answer it then for the sake of not letting the question "hanging" after having managed to get a probable match.